# AS3 - 3596: Duplicate variable definition

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math, variables, duplicates

Okay, I've been working all day on this error and had no luck, I searched everywhere, andall questions hee for an answer, got a couple of ones but none worked out for me. The code used to work fine but once I modified a text and a couple of lines from the script, I started having this "Duplicate variable definition." with a code totally unrelated with what I edited (I only edited the music player script that I was having problems with). The code I'm having problem goes like this:

```
     var mufl:* = size + 0.2;
     size = size + 0.2;
     mufl0 = Math.sin(mufl) * 8 + 4;
  1  var mufl:* = red + RED_STEP;
     red = red + RED_STEP;
  2  var mufl:* = blue + BLUE_STEP;
     blue = blue + BLUE_STEP;
  3  var mufl:* = green + GREEN_STEP;
     green = green + GREEN_STEP;
```

Math functions:

```
 mufl5 = Math.sin(mufl) * 128 + 127 << 16 | Math.sin(mufl) * 128 + 127 << 8 | Math.sin(mufl) * 128 + 127;
        list.push(new SpiritPlayer(px, py, mufl2, mufl3, mufl4, mufl5));
```

I keep getting the error on the lins 1,2 and 3 (where the var is)

The code uses some Math functions,etc... The main purpose of this code is to create a colorful waves (much like the the old Media Player 11 "Alchemy" visualization), but would change color and shapes everytime the user uses his mouse. The final purpose of this is to make a colorful, interactive music player for a online radio we are trying to build.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be perfectly accurate (and tedious) — it's actually a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're defining it multiple times in the same scope. Declare it once in your scope and THEN assign it.

```
  var mufl:*;
  mufl = size + 0.2;
  size = size + 0.2;
  mufl0 = Math.sin(mufl) * 8 + 4;
  mufl = red + RED_STEP;
  red = red + RED_STEP;
  mufl = blue + BLUE_STEP;
  blue = blue + BLUE_STEP;
  mufl = green + GREEN_STEP;
  green = green + GREEN_STEP;
```

Comment: I don't really understand what this code could possibly be doing. the last six lines are just re-assigning the same var over and over.

Comment: Yeah, its assigning over so I can set the other functions. I did declared it only once, but I get a different error once I do it:  ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property * on global.
 at com.fl.spirit::SpiritPlayer/::update()

Comment: It used to work fine, I mean, I never touched this code once it was finished, I only edited the code of the player that is saved on another .as

Comment: "Yeah, its assigning over so I can set the other functions." Makes absolutely no sense. Why are you using a wildcard type declaration? What is it, a number? and int? try using a real type. Can you post the whole function?

Comment: The whole function is pretty big, but thanks, I think I managed to fix the mess. I've divided the function in 3, each one assigned differently so it wont duplicate, then set the the main .as file to process each one separatly... Now gotta reset the playr for it... Thanks for the help anyway ^^